# Material UI 5.0 Typescript React Custom theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have problem with customization of a theme in Material UI 5.0 using typescript.

theme.ts

```
    import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Theme {
        custom: {
            buttonWidth: string;
        };
    }
    interface ThemeOptions {
        custom: {
            buttonWidth: string;
        };
    }
}

export const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#00F',
        },
    },
    typography: {
        body1: {
            fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
        },
    },
    custom: {
        buttonWidth: '200px',
    },
});

export const CustomTheme= typeof theme;
```

But when I try to use it, it doesn't work

```
// CustomTheme imported
<Button sx={{ width: (theme: CustomTheme) => theme.custom.buttonWidth}} />
```

It's showed as any or I have this typescript error:

> Did you mean 'typeof CustomTheme'?

My question is what is the right way to implement a custom theme with Material UI 5.0 and typescript

package.json

```
    // other dependencies
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
```

Comment: If you can please share your `<Button />` component

Comment: Did you put the `Button` inside `ThemeProvider` with your custom theme?

Comment: use useTheme hook you can get a right Theme

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

In material v5 you can override the default style by using `styleOverrides`

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#00F',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          width: 200,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

and this style will be applied for every single `Button`

Reference link: https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides