# How to have custom colors as props with mui v5 react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I wish to add one or more custom color props values to the MUI Button component. I followed https://javascript.plainenglish.io/extend-material-ui-theme-in-typescript-a462e207131f, which almost worked. I used the custom properties I created in the createPalette.d.ts file, but when I try to use that in a custom component, it throws an error, and I cannot use the custom color.

Error faced:

[image: Error]

I followed [Can't customize color palette types on Material UI theme in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424596/cant-customize-color-palette-types-on-material-ui-theme-in-typescript), [Material UI 5.0 Typescript React Custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266727/material-ui-5-0-typescript-react-custom-theme), [How to extend Material-UI Theme with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120760/how-to-extend-material-ui-theme-with-typescript) but no luck.

But, it is working here for the JavaScript version: [Can you add an additional color in Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408516/can-you-add-an-additional-color-in-material-ui). But, I am unable to follow it for the typescript version

As there are multiple files, I created a sandbox for the same. https://codesandbox.io/s/async-rgb-9m6ulo?file=/src/App.tsx

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add appcolor as a possible type in your `ButtonPropsType.ts`

```js
type ButtonPropsType = {
  color?:
    | "inherit"
    | "primary"
    | "secondary"
    | "success"
    | "error"
    | "info"
    | "warning"
    | "appcolor"; //<-- Here
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?: "text" | "outlined" | "contained";
};
```

Alternatively if you want to dynamically add options as needed, mui has an interface for that.

#### `ButtonPropsTypes.ts`

```js
import { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material";

type ButtonPropsType = {
  color?: ButtonProps["color"];
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?: "text" | "outlined" | "contained";
};

export default ButtonPropsType;
```

#### `createPalette.d.ts`

```js
import * as createPalette from "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface PaletteOptions {
    appcolor?: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
  interface Palette {
    appcolor: PaletteColor;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    appcolor;
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck bro. Can you check in the sandbox link if it is working for you? its not working for me :'(

Comment: @GrandWhiz See here, [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-frost-9c480k?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: wow. Thank you so much, bro. I was stuck in this for two days. And just curious, Will it work for multiple colors?

Comment: As long as you declare it in all the modules in `createPalette.d.ts`, and do the same steps for when you added the appcolor.