# How to extent Material UI v5 theme with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

*Yes, I know this question has been asked before but ...*

I want to add some more color variant as like `success`, `warning` and add more options under `background` (`palette.background`). Like `lite`. (need this colors work with dark theme too)

I'm extending the theme like this

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    preset?: {
      p1: string;
      p2: string;
    };
    background?: {
      b1: string,
      b2: string
    }
  }
}
```

but getting following error:

```
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'background' must be of type 'Partial<TypeBackground> | undefined', but here has type '{ b1: string; b2: string; } | undefined'.
```

How to extend MUI theme properly in this case

Answer (score 1):

As [Cody Duong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17954209/cody-duong) answered for [How to have custom colors as props with mui v5 react typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665399/how-to-have-custom-colors-as-props-with-mui-v5-react-typescript), you can follow the same for having custom color variant props.

If you check the error message, `PaletteOptions` is already having the background property as

```
export interface PaletteOptions {
  primary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  secondary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  error?: PaletteColorOptions;
  warning?: PaletteColorOptions;
  info?: PaletteColorOptions;
  success?: PaletteColorOptions;
  mode?: PaletteMode;
  tonalOffset?: PaletteTonalOffset;
  contrastThreshold?: number;
  common?: Partial<CommonColors>;
  grey?: ColorPartial;
  text?: Partial<TypeText>;
  divider?: string;
  action?: Partial<TypeAction>;
  background?: Partial<TypeBackground>;
  getContrastText?: (background: string) => string;
}
```

Where background type is

```
export interface TypeBackground {
  default: string;
  paper: string;
}
```

Which is why you are getting the

`TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'background' must be of type 'Partial<TypeBackground> | undefined', but here has type '{ b1: string; b2: string; } | undefined'.` error

I will try to edit this answer with a clear solution in the future. But, at least now, I was able to give you an idea. Keep Coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypeBackground {
    b1: string,
    b2: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.